# Spring @Transactional not working in ApplicationServer

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-transactions

We have a Spring-Boot application exposing some REST endpoints. We allow for this application to be operated standalone (as executable jar) or as a war to be deployed in a wildfly-11 application-server.

The class defining the REST-endpoints is marked `@RestController @Transactional(REQUIRES_NEW)` (both on class level, obviously). When running standalone, everything works as expected but when deployed in wildfly, the rollback on exceptions does not work. We established this by sending the exact same REST-message while operating on the exact same database.

We have confirmed via debugging that the final frames of the stacktrace is identical in both cases and especially in both cases we see a transactional-proxy around our REST-controller bean.

One difference would be, that within wildfly the application will use a jndi-datasource, prepared by wildfly while standalone the spring-boot will manage the database-connections.

Any idea what is wrong here?

**Edit**

I just tried explicitly invoking setRollbackOnly on the `JtaTransactionmanager` from within my code. The transaction will still commit. This sort of looks like a bug in Spring Boot to me.

**Edit 2**

Debugging further reveals that the transaction seems to be set to autocommit - every statement is immediately written to the database. This seems to be in violation to the annotation `@Transactional` and also to the fact that Spring creates a transactional proxy around my bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reasons beyond my understanding the **default** transactional behaviour when deploying a spring-boot webapp to an application-server is `auto-commit`.

The solution to this problem is to enrich your application-configuration with the property `spring.datasource.tomcat.default-auto-commit=false`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a full answer - just a reasoning. `JNDI` is usally used at the app server layer whereas `JDBC` - at the application layer. At the App server layer are used global transaction settins that are overriding app settings. Follow the [spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) to get more

Comment: I assume that this is the root cause. However, Spring does make the promise, its declarative transaction-configuration works standalone as well as jta. So something must be broken here, if the same artifact behaves differently whether on standalone or on AS.

Comment: well, i agree. Once i've faced with WF and it was a big pain( so, i hope you'll figure this problem out. Please inform int topic if so. Good luck!)